# GWT : Getting a 404 error when unit testing RequestBuilder

Tags: gwt

I use the GWT RequestBuilder, and  for testing purposes, I'd like to load a json file in the server.
It works perfectly with the DevMode, but throw a 404 error with GWTTestCase.

With RPC, there is a fix adding `<servlet path=".." class="..."/>`, but what can I do with static content ?

I could easily use `@TextResource`, but it's not the goal of my UnitTest (which is in fact a functionnal test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static resources can be *bundled* with a module by putting them in [the module's *public path*](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules).

Answer (score 1):

I used (once again) Thomas's answer to resolve the problem. My module is `io.robusta.fora.comments.Comment.gwt.xml` and I've put my user.json file in the `io.robsuta.fora.comments.resources` package.

I had so to add in Comment.gwt.xml file : `<public path="resources"/>`

Then the GWTTestCase is straightforward :

```
public class GwtRestClientTest extends GWTTestCase{

    @Override
    public String getModuleName() {
        return "io.robusta.fora.comments.Comments";
    }


    public void testGET(){

         String base =   GWT.getModuleBaseURL();
         System.out.println(base); //-> http://192.168.0.10:53551/io.robusta.fora.comments.Comments.JUnit/

        GwtRestClient client = new GwtRestClient(base); //base url
        AsyncCallback<String> cb = new AsyncCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                System.out.println(result);//->{id:1,email:"jo@robusta.io"}
                finishTest();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                caught.printStackTrace();
            }
        };

        client.GET("user.json", null, cb);//fetch my json file with no params
        delayTestFinish(3000);
    }

}
```

Comment: Note: if you want to load your JSON file from sources with Super Dev Mode, then you can replace `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` with `GWT.getModuleBaseForStaticFiles()`. I'll update the docs (if I find the time before I forget about it).

Comment: https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/4340 Feel free to comment if you think it can be enhanced.